# No value for remote.gerrit.url found in configuration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, egit, pull-request

Whenever I start pulling from eclipse git repositories I get alert box stating that the current branch is not configured for pull. No value for remote.gerrit.url found in configuration.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you include the contents of `.git/config` of the repository?

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[branch "master"]
 remote = gerrit
 merge = refs/heads/master
 rebase = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = (url is correct but its private so not displaying)
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "gerrit"]
 receivepack = git receive-pack --reviewer (name iven)--cc ReleaseManagement-Team@xxx.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these lines in the config, your `master` branch is configured to fetch the `gerrit` remote on pull:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = gerrit
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

You need to either add `url` to the `[remote "gerrit"]` section or change the `remote` value above to `origin`.